# IIS URL Rerouting MVC 404 Error - Hangfire

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add an MVC site under a domain where there is an existing site. The new site is just a simple mvc site to show a hangfire dashboard. I'm using IIS 8.5.

The current site is an old ASP.NET Web Forms site and will not allow the routing to the new MVC application and I get a 404.

The old site needs to be accessible at https://example.com and I need to be able to access the Hangfire site at https://example.com/Reporting/hangfire.

I have the MVC application configured and it works when the physical path of the Web Forms site is not pointing to the root folder (example.com).

I am new to the routing configuration in IIS so I am not sure if there is a URL Rewrite rule that would be useful for this or if need to do something else.

**Edit**

This is the root site, its a web forms site deployed by someone else. I added the MVC site as an web application and it uses a different app pool. I get a 404 in this case because the web forms app is handling the routing and its never getting to the MVC app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @mason Sorry. It's ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: Why not add the Hangfire site to the Web Forms site? Why do you need as a separate app? You don't need any rewrite rule either way. Just configure the MVC site as a [virtual application](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) under the Web Forms application.

Comment: @mason I have it added as a virtual application but the Web Forms applications is overriding the routing. I get a 404 when trying to get to the  https://example.com/Reporting web application.

Comment: I think you need to describe your IIS configuration better.

Comment: @mason I added some additional information.

Comment: Are you sure the 404 isn't coming from the MVC app, and that Hangfire isn't misconfigured? How do you know which application is generating the 404?

Comment: @mason I know that the MVC app is not generating the error. I tested this on our staging server by removing the web forms app physical path. When I did this I was able to get to the MVC app and see the hangfire dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by deploying the site under a sub-domain; I had to convince our admin to allow this. The MVC site worked on its own but never when nested under the Web Forms site.